# How to feed openshift an environment variable via jenkins config file?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, openshift

I am trying to update the environment variables in openshift via jenkinsfile. I can update the environment variables via folowing command but the problem with the command is that I have to enter all variables in the jenkinsfile so it is not secure and the jenkinsfile looks very long and ugly at times.

"command "oc set env dc/prj -e te1=tes -e tes2=tes2  Ntes=ntes""

Usually for other servers, I used to add all environment variables ina  config file in jenkins and pass the config file to server directly.

Just wondering if anyone has done anything where I can pass all my environment variables via jenkinsfile using jenkins config file to the openshift containers.

Thank you

Comment: is it mandatory to config through jenkins config file or would you like to know other procedure using openshift templates? If so I can provide some info which we are following in our project.

Comment: It is not mandatory and would like to see your different approach too.THank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use **Openshift templates for deployments** or changes. This way helps to code your infrastructure, basically **Infrastructure As Code for versioning** and helps to replicate the same across environments.

For example, consider this **deployment template**:

```
$ cat deployment.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
    name: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
      deploymentconfig: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
    strategy:
      resources: {}
      rollingParams:
        intervalSeconds: 1
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        timeoutSeconds: 600
        updatePeriodSeconds: 1
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
          deploymentconfig: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
           - name: param1
             value: value1
           - name: param2
             value: value2
          image: "${DOCKER_IMAGE}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: "${APPLICATION_NAME}"
          ports:
            - containerPort: PORT1
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: ${HEALTHCHECK_PATH}
              port: ${LIVENESS_PORT} 
              scheme: HTTPS
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: ${HEALTHCHECK_PATH}
              port: ${READINESS_PORT}
              scheme: HTTPS
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: ${CPU_MAX}
              memory: ${MEMORY_MAX}
            requests:
              cpu: ${CPU_DEFAULT}
              memory: ${MEMORY_DEFAULT}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    test: false
    triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
  status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Above template has **2 variables in it and deployment config** is created using the command `oc apply -f deployment.yaml`.

```
- name: param1
  value: value1
- name: param2
  value: value2
```

So now **to update environment variables in Openshift**, I suggest to add the new variable in the template like this:

```
- name: param1
  value: value1
- name: param2
  value: value2
- name: param3
  value: value3
```

Use the **same command** `oc apply -f deployment.yaml` to **update the new environment variables** or the same command can be used to update existing parameters.

**Openshift has the intelligence to update the config only if there is a change in configuration**. This way not only your **environment variables** can be updated but also any other configuration like CPU, Memory, replicas, docker images and so on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will give it a try but this sounds like a right approach. I will save the deployment.yaml that I got after first deployment in the Jenkins config file and update the config file everytime I have to add new variables or any other changes to the deployment and then deploy using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the approach as you did before from a file you may be able to break this into two steps:

1. Create configmap from a file:
   `oc create configmap my-config --from-file=path/to/bar`
2. Set the environment variables from a configmap:
   `oc set env --from=configmap/my-config dc/prj`

Comment: The problem here I am facing is that everytime I am creating a config map it is creating key as the file name and value as everything that is in file. It would be a perfect solution if I can create key=value pair from either the key=value from data part of configmap yaml or just mapping all key=value directly from the file.

Comment: I am trying to update a config map with an edited  copy of  yaml file but just adding some more fields in the data part so that I can add/edit env variables from a yaml file.  If there is any way to create a configmap by adding a yaml file whose data field will be used as key value pair then the solution would be perfect. Thank you @PhilipGough

Comment: Again trying to rephrase my problem here. I am trying to add/update  item(when creating config map from web console)  directly from yaml file via cli.

Comment: Not sure how feasible it is for you but could try something like https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to parse the file and add the k=v --from-literal

Comment: actually you may try "--from-env-file" flag to create configmap. It takes multiline file with lines like KEY=value and creates configmap. I think it should solve your problem.